# How should I create Google Action fulfilment endpoint with C++?

Tags: c++, actions-on-google

I just start to use Google Action and want to develop an action to stream my raspberry pi IP camera video on PC/Mobile with Google Home using voice control. I have read throw the guide on Google Action page for Action SDK
, https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/. However, I am getting stuck on the fulfillment part.

How do I create the fulfillment endpoint with C++?

Is that mean I will need to set RESTful API on my server side to handle the request? And is it using POST/GET request for the JSON?

Using the action package example, how would my fulfillment endpoint to handle actions.intent.MAIN and com.example.sekai.BUY?

```html
"actions": [
    {
      "name": "MAIN",
      "intent": {
        "name": "actions.intent.MAIN"
      },
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "sekai-app"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "BUY",
      "intent": {
        "name": "com.example.sekai.BUY",
        "parameters": [{
          "name": "color",
          "type": "SchemaOrg_Color"
        }],
        "trigger": {
          "queryPatterns": [
            "find some $SchemaOrg_Color:color sneakers",
            "buy some blue suede shoes",
            "get running shoes"
          ]
        }
      },
```

The guide has shown the handling of using their NodeJS library

```
app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', handleTextIntent);
app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', handleMaiIntent);
```

I see most of the tutorial and library are using Nodejs, however, I want it to consist of my existing server which used C++. Thank you for help.

Comment: You may want to look at this doc, which shows some of the JSON responses: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#tab2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a REST API.

You *do* need to be able to receive (and decode) a POST with a [JSON body](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/conversation-webhook#json) at a public HTTPS web endpoint and to [reply with JSON](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/conversation-webhook#response_format).

The detailed format of the JSON are more extensive (they can include more fields, depending on the scenario), but the [request](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest) can look something like this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "userId": "wCBxFjVLK8I+nxIXfFOHEf/iAvvaTFuzUdBw6Gv5K3Q="
    },
    "conversation": {
        "conversationId": "1494709404186",
        "type": "NEW"
    },
    "inputs": [
        {
            "intent": "actions.intent.MAIN",
            "rawInputs": [
                {
                    "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
                    "query": "talk to my test app"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "surface": {
        "capabilities": [
            {
                "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
            },
            {
                "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and you need to [respond](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse) with something like this

```
{
    "conversationToken": "{\"state\":null,\"data\":{}}",
    "expectUserResponse": true,
    "expectedInputs": [
        {
            "inputPrompt": {
                "richInitialPrompt": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "simpleResponse": {
                                "textToSpeech": "Howdy! I can tell you fun facts about almost any number, like 42. What do you have in mind?",
                                "displayText": "Howdy! I can tell you fun facts about almost any number. What do you have in mind?"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "suggestions": []
                }
            },
            "possibleIntents": [
                {
                    "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: ok. Thanks, I thought handling POST request needs to use RESTful. I think I messed up what RESTful is. For now, I think I can just use boost to handle the POST request
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

I am not very familar with handling POST, GET and JSON thing. Gonna try it out